# Why the result of serialization of a class is different on different machine?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a class `Header` which looks like

```
/// <remarks />
[GeneratedCode("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://www.schemas.com/IntegrationApplication-instance")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.schemas.com/IntegrationApplication-instance", IsNullable = true)]
public class Header
{
    private string operationField;

    private string requestIdField;

    private DateTime sendDateField;

    private string senderSystemNameField;

    /// <remarks />
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string Operation
    {
        get
        {
            return operationField;
        }
        set
        {
            operationField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks />
    public string RequestId
    {
        get
        {
            return requestIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            requestIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks />
    public DateTime SendDate
    {
        get
        {
            return sendDateField;
        }
        set
        {
            sendDateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks />
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string SenderSystemName
    {
        get
        {
            return senderSystemNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            senderSystemNameField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

When I serialize it on my machine, SendDate is specified, but for my surprise when I run serialization code on another machine SendDate is somehow missed. The piece of code I use is:

```
var header = new Header()
            {
                Operation = "new ope",
                RequestId = "",
                SendDate = DateTime.Now,
                SenderSystemName = "asd"
            };
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Header));
var sb = new StringBuilder();
serializer.Serialize(new StringWriter(sb, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), header);
```

Why the results of this code is different on different machines?

Comment: This looks weird. Are you sure that you are running the exact same code on the other machine? So the `<SendDate>` node is omitted from the resulting XML?

Comment: Same .net framework version in both machines?

Comment: I had this yesterday, same framework, different compilers. 1 was compiled in VS2008, the other VS2010 (.net 4). Is the header (GeneratedCode) different?

Comment: @Darin, I swear the code is equal, .NET is 4.0 on both computers. The `<SendDate>` is just omitted. I'm gonna create a brand new solution with those classes and re-check.

Comment: @TheCodeKing yes, I just copied the solution files and run the code

Answer (score 2):

I thing it is a culture issue.  I don't see the deserialization code but it could be that this code expect the date to be in a different format.  If this code does not specify culture, the regional settings of the machine on wich the code runs will be taken.  Check that the regional settings of both machines are the same, specially date format.

Comment: I would have understood if the value of SendDate tag was incorrect. But it is just omitted

Comment: Besides which, `XmlSerializer` should be [de]serialising dates using ISO 8601, and produce output which is culture-independent.

Comment: @javros : it might be that the date is not even recognize as a date and then ignored.

Comment: @VdesmedT how that might be? I set the date so the `XmlSerializer` should include it anyway. But it doesn't :(

Comment: So the Date is well in the XML, you have validate that right ?  Still it can be that the Deserialization code does not recognize it as a date because it expect a different format. Where is your DESerialization code ?